# how to convert time from 24H to 12H then subtract the two times

Tags: time, conversion

I have a file that collects time stamps of HH:MM need to add one hour to the 1st column and convert the both columns from 24H to 12H then subtract them.

Output in the file I collected the times from:

```
Start End     Total Run Time
00:00 05:39
01:31 06:02
00:48 06:24
23:46 04:50
00:05 05:12
00:06 05:04
00:04 05:10
00:10 05:10
00:00 04:51
00:10 05:33
23:41 04:15
```

I want to give the total run time, between these two columns.

so the 1st time stamps should be `01:00 05:39` before subtracting to get the total time run `01:00-05:39`.

I tried with just this command to subtract but the 24H to 12H and adding one hour to the $1 1st column, just confuses me.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { $3 = $2 - $1 } 1'
```

Comment: Not really a Ubuntu question  but one perhaps for another site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490764/subtract-time-using-bash

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply subtract datetime objects like `01:00` and `05:39` in `awk` (although GNU awk has its own [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) that you could use to do it).

Having said that, formating a datetime *difference* as as datetime is somewhat questionable. Miller's builtin `strptime`/`strftime` implementations *look like* they will handle it - including correctly rolling over the day boundary.

Ex. given

```
$ cat file
Start End
00:00 05:39
01:31 06:02
00:48 06:24
23:46 04:50
00:05 05:12
00:06 05:04
00:04 05:10
00:10 05:10
00:00 04:51
00:10 05:33
23:41 04:15
```

then

```
$ mlr --pprint put -S '
    ${Total Run Time} = strftime(strptime(${End},"%H:%M") - 3600 - strptime(${Start},"%H:%M"),"%H:%M")
  ' file
Start End   Total Run Time
00:00 05:39 04:39
01:31 06:02 03:31
00:48 06:24 04:36
23:46 04:50 04:04
00:05 05:12 04:07
00:06 05:04 03:58
00:04 05:10 04:06
00:10 05:10 04:00
00:00 04:51 03:51
00:10 05:33 04:23
23:41 04:15 03:34
```